# Prove that $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ with Taylor's polynomials $1$ and $2$

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I have to prove the inequality, that
$x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ with the use of $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$.
I got that $T_1(x)=x$ and $T_2(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. I also got that $R_2(x)=\frac{2}{6(\xi+1)^3}$.

In the second task I had to prove the left inequality with monotony criteria, so I proved that $\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)'=1-x$ and $\left(\ln(x+1)\right)'=1/(x+1)$ and proved for all $x>0$ that $1-x>1/(x+1)$.

I had to prove the right inequality with mean theorem, but my group partner did that so I cannot explain how we did it.

I wrote that, because I have to prove the inequality with Taylor, that's why I openend a new question since the question has already be answered earlier but with our second way of proval.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${ \epsilon _1 (x) := \log(1+x) - x }.$ Note ${ \epsilon _1 '(x) }$ ${ = \frac{1}{1+x} -1 }$ ${ = \frac{-x}{1+x} }.$ So ${ \epsilon _1 (0) = 0 }$ and ${ \epsilon _1 '(x) \lt 0 }$ for ${ x \gt 0 }.$ Hence ${ \epsilon _1 (x) \lt 0 }$ for ${ x \gt 0 },$ that is ${ \log(1+x) \lt x }$ for ${ x \gt 0 }.$

Let ${ \epsilon _2 (x) := \log(1+x) - (x - \frac{x ^2}{2}) }.$ Note ${ \epsilon _2 '(x) }$ ${ = \frac{1}{1+x} - (1- x) }$ ${ = \frac{x ^2}{1+x} }.$ So ${ \epsilon _2 (0) = 0 }$ and ${ \epsilon _2 '(x) \gt 0 }$ for ${ x \gt 0 }.$ Hence ${ \epsilon _2 (x) \gt 0 }$ for ${ x \gt 0 },$ that is ${ \log(1+x) \gt x - \frac{x ^2}{2} }$ for ${ x \gt 0 }.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\xi >0$ since, by the Taylor's theorem with Lagrange's remainder, it belongs to the segment of endpoints $0$ and $x$ and by hypothesis $x>0$. Knowing this, you can estimate the quantities that depends on $\xi$.